# Update a value dynamically with a $variable inside a while loop

Tags: php, database

I think I got a pretty good question. I produced a loop with 2 input radio button inside of each loop. When you press on one of these radio buttons, my function ChangeIt changes a value inside my database. This is where I am stuck : I have an ID column for each rows and I want to find that ID and put it into my ChangeIt function, into my statement (at the very end, I must put a dynamic ID). My Loop shows each rows inside of separated divs. I put a variable $id in my while loop, so I was thinking about, maybe, put my function ChangeIt inside my function Admin()? is this possible? THX!

Any ideas?

PHP on index.php

```
if(isset($_POST['confirmation'])){
$conf = $_POST['confirmation'];
    if($conf == 'Accepter'){
        $object = new User;
        $object->ChangeIt($conf,$id);
    } else if($conf == 'Refuser'){
        $object = new User;
        $object->ChangeIt($conf,$id);
    }   
}
```

PHP

```
public function Admin(){
        $st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM form");
        $st->execute();
        while($r = $st->fetch()){
            $id = $r['ID'];
            echo '<hr>';
            echo 'Username : ' .$r['username'].' <br>';
            echo 'Adresse : ' .$r['Adresse'].' <br>';
            echo 'Met : ' .$r['Met'].' <br>';
            echo 'Age : ' .$r['Age'].' <br>';
            echo 'Statut : ' .$r['Statut'].' <br>';
            echo '<form action="compte.php" method="post">';
            echo '<input type="radio" name="confirmation" value="Accepter"> Accepter';
            echo '<input type="radio" name="confirmation" value="Refuser"> Refuser<br>';
            echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirmer">';
            echo '</form>';
            echo '<hr>';
        }
    }
public function ChangeIt($ans,$id){
        $st = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `test`.`form` SET `Statut` = '$ans' WHERE `form`.`ID` = '$id'");
        $st->execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy to send GET/POST data in associative array format. Change your input names to `confirmation[id goes here...]`:

```
echo '<input type="radio" name="confirmation['.$id.']" value="Accepter"> Accepter';
echo '<input type="radio" name="confirmation['.$id.']" value="Refuser"> Refuser<br>';
```

you can put form tags `<form>...</form>` and submit button `<input type="submit"...` outside your loop if you like.

with form inside loop your `$_POST` will look like this:

```
Array('123' => 'Accepter')
```

with form outside loop your `$_POST` will look like this:

```
Array('123' => 'Accepter', '124' => 'Refuser', '125' => 'Refuser', ...)
```

so you need to change your update code:

```
$conf_arr = $_POST['confirmation'];
foreach($conf_arr as $id => $conf) {
    if($conf == 'Accepter'){
        $object = new User;
        $object->ChangeIt($conf,$id);
    } else if($conf == 'Refuser'){
        $object = new User;
        $object->ChangeIt($conf,$id);
    }   
}
```

Please mind you need to escape SQL values to prevent [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Thanks you! Everything works just fine. There is something I don't understand, escape SQL values? All I am sending as values are within radio button, is this really important to escape sql values then?

Comment: @user3371099 someone can mess with your database sending inproper data, please read about sql injection